# object HTMLLIElement getting outputted instead of expected value

Tags: php, javascript

Hey I have a problem in Javascript-PHP variable passing
heres my php code:

`<li id="' . $todo1 . '" class="items">' . $todo1 . '<button onclick="ajaxdelete(' . $todo1 . ')">Delete</button></li>`

and heres the javascript function

```
 function ajaxdelete(x){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "ajaxtododelete.php";
var vars = "todo="+x;
hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
}
 }
 hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request

}
```

and hers my ajax file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$todo = $_POST['todo'];
print "$todo";

$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM todo WHERE todo='$todo'");
?>
```

So instead of outputting the value of '$todo1'(which is wat i want) it outputs :
  object HTMLLIElement.Any way around this?

Comment: What does your markup (the `<li>` tag) look like when rendered?

Comment: its looks like a normal li tag would look like

Comment: That was request for more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a major hole in your application for SQL injection.  Second, you need to quote the identifer so you are passing the value of the id in the function call instead of a reference to the element itself.  Third, you probably ought to be using a framework for this and applying the handlers unobtrusively.

```
'<li id="' . $todo1 . '" class="items">' . $todo1 . '<button onclick="ajaxdelete(\'' . $todo1 . '\')">Delete</button></li>'
```

better (using jQuery)

```
'<li id="' . $todo1 . '" class="items">' . $todo1 . '<button>Delete</button></li>'


<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
           $('.items').on('click', function() {
               var $li = $(this).closest('li');
                   id = $li.attr('id');
               $.post( "ajaxtodelete.php", { "todo" : id }, function() {
                       $li.remove();
               });
           });
     });
</script>
```

And fix your PHP to use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation in case someone decides to modify the ids using a browser debugger and change the id in to a SQL command that will drop your entire database -- or retrieve its contents for more nefarious purposes.

Comment: Thank you!That totally worked!and thanks for your advice on injection,I wasnt aware of that! :)